# How many integer points does my favorite ellipse go through?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, diophantine-equations

The equation of the ellipse interpolating the six lattice points $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(d-1,d)$, $(d,d)$, $(d,d-1)$ in the plane for a fixed $d$ (at least 3) is
$$
x^2+y^2 - \frac{2(d-1)}{d}xy-x-y =0
$$
By construction, the ellipse is symmetric with respect to the lines $x=y$ and $y=d-x$.

I would like to know exactly how many lattice points this ellipse goes through, depending on $d$. Computations suggest that the number is six most of the time and sometimes ten. No other numbers occured. An explanation of that fact (if it's true) is also very welcome.

Comment: "Contains"? Do you mean, "goes through"?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: For $d=200$ and $d=468$ there are $14$ points on the curve.

Comment: See the "Added" section in my (first) answer below what could be salvaged from my withdrawn (second) answer.

Comment: For $d=22848=2^6\times 3\times 7\times 17$ there are $22$ integer points on the curve.  There are $13$ values $d<10^4$ where there are $18$ points: $1008,1190,1320,1530,1568,2448,5440,6650,6864,8432,8883,9048$ and $9328$.  Each of these is also a product of fairly small primes.

Answer (score 5):

Your equation can be rewritten as 
$$ (x+y-d)^2+(2d-1)(x-y)^2=d(2f+d). $$
This shows that the number of integral solutions $(x,y)$ is much the same as the number of divisors of the right hand side in the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1-2d})$. Of course there are issues of parity to consider, but these are not too relevant. For general $d$ it is quite subtle to give an explicit formula for the number of divisors , because the class group is nontrivial (I recommend the book Cox: Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$). At any rate, the number of solutions can be as large as $\exp(c\log f/\log\log f)$ for a constant $c=c(d)>0$, and it is easy to construct concrete examples when the number of solutions is much larger than $10$. I will give examples in the next paragraph (I plan to add another paragraph later, for slightly larger $d$).

For $d=2$ we are working in the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ which is a unique factorization domain. It is known that in this ring any rational prime $\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ splits into a product of two primes. This means that if $2f+d=2f+2$ has many such prime factors, the number of divisors will be large. For example, for $f=7*13*19*31-1=53598$, SAGE gives me $96$ solutions starting with $(-266,-144)$ and ending with $(268,146)$. For $f=7*13*19*31*37-1=1983162$, SAGE gives me $192$ solutions starting with $(-1625,-828)$ and ending with $(1627,830)$.

For $d=10$ we are working in the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19})$ which is a unique factorization domain. It is known that in this ring any rational prime $\equiv 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 16, 17\pmod{19}$ splits into a product of two primes. This means that if $2f+d=2f+10$ has many such prime factors, the number of divisors will be large. For example, for $f=5*7*11*17*23-5=150530$, SAGE gives me $96$ solutions starting with $(-885,-802)$ and ending with $(895,812)$. For $f=5*7*11*17*23*43-5=6473000$, SAGE gives me $192$ solutions starting with $(-5831,-5290)$ and ending with $(5841,5300)$.

**Added.** It turns out that the original question concerned the special case $f=0$. I discussed that case in a second answer that was incorrect, unfortunately. Here I collect what could be salvaged from that answer as it might be useful for later investigations. The equation can be rewritten as
$$ (2d-1)(x-y)^2=(x+y)(2d-x-y), $$
where all factors can be seen to be nonnegative integers. The case $x=y$ yields the lattice points $(0,0)$ and $(d,d)$. In the case $x\neq y$ we have a factorization into positive integers
$$2d-1=d_1d_2,\quad (x-y)^2=b_1b_2,\quad x+y=d_1b_1,\quad 2d-x-y=d_2b_2,$$
and the case when $d_1$ or $d_2$ equals $1$ yields the other four listed lattice points $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, $(d-1,d)$, $(d,d-1)$. These observations certainly show (without any algebraic number theory) that the number of solutions is $O_\epsilon(d^\epsilon)$, and a good approach seems to consider the system
$$ d_1d_2=2d-1,\quad b_1b_2=\square, \quad d_1b_1+d_2b_2=2d. $$
It is worthwhile to note that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are coprime here, which implies that the six listed lattice points are the only ones when $2d-1$ is a prime power.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, it is not quite what I meant. I guess, writing $f = x^2+y^2-s(d-1)/d xy -x -y$ is confusing. What I really want to know is, how many lattice points lie on the plane curve defined by $x^2+y^2-2(d-1)/d xy-x-y =0$. So $f$ was meant to just be a (superfluous) symbol for the polynomial.
I'm sorry for the confusion. Thanks for answering.

Comment: I see. I will look into the clarified question as time permits.

Answer (score 2):

(Not an answer, just examples.)
Here are Rainer's ellipses for $d=5$ and $d=8$.
The first passes through $6$ lattice points, the second through $10$.

   [image: d=5]

   [image: d=8]

Comment: What is that good for? Given the five points which lie on the curve, it's obvious that the curves look like that.

Comment: I was merely illustrating the OP's $6$- & $10$-points observation.

Answer (score 1):

If the ratio of " $d$ " negative then the equation can be rewritten as:

$$a^2+b^2-\frac{2(d+1)ab}{d}-a-b=0$$

Then this equation. If there is a solution - they are infinitely many.

Finding solutions-it factor.  To factor.  $d=tq$

We use the solutions of the equation Pell.   $p^2-(2d+1)s^2=t$

Then the solutions are.

$$a=q((2d+1)s+p)s$$

$$b=q((2d+1)s-p)s$$

$$...$$

$$a=q(s-p)p$$

$$b=-q(s+p)p$$